# TinyMCE hook breaks Wordpress media preview in editor

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, mediaelement.js, tinymce-4

I am extending WP editor with custom button.
Problem happens when I use this hook:

```
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'mytheme_icon_picker' );
```

This is used to enqueue custom scripts and styles.
Even the empty function leads to media player not being displayed/styled in editor.
This leads me to believe that hooking to `mce_css`, breaks WP enqueueing media-player assets.

Does anyone know what hook to use, to correctly include custom files without breaking default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're using is a filter. It must return a value.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_css

Your function should append the CSS URL to the existing list of CSS files.

```
function wpse_icon_picker( $mce_css ) {
    if ( ! empty( $mce_css ) ) {
        $mce_css .= ',';
    }

    $mce_css .= 'enter URL to CSS here';

    return $mce_css;
}
add_filter( 'mce_css', 'wpse_icon_picker' );
```